# Qt4 to Qt5 Linking Error

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake

I seem to be having a little issue, I am trying to port Qt4 app to Qt5, and everything is working until I get to the linking part. I walked through the QT migration guide and did everything to the point of where it compiles, but it won't link.

It keeps dying on ld: library not found for -lQt5Widgets or something, I am not sure if I missed something or I am suppose to add something to my make file, but a basic Hello World application runs fine.

My .pro file has the basic stuff in it

```
CONFIG = qt uic resources thread stl warn_on
QT += core gui xml

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

*-g++ : QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-sign-compare

DEPENDPATH += crypto dialogs export forms import lib translations res widgets
INCLUDEPATH += . lib crypto plugins/interfaces export import dialogs
```

And then a bunch of debug turning on and stuff to create PLIST and such, which even if removed don't fix the issue so they are not relevant (you can see it at https://github.com/relgames/keepassx/blob/master/src/src.pro)

For some reason it is trying to `-l` the Qt frameworks rather then `-framework` For example it generates

`-L/Users/user/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Xml -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core`

On the linking step, but that should be

`-F/Users/user/Qt/5.1.1/clang_64/lib -framework QtWidgets -framework QtXml -framework QtGui -framework QtCore`

Changing it and running it via terminal then works, but obviously that won't work cause Qt hasn't finished all it's steps. Any idea why this may be happening? It seems to be doing it like it would on Linux, rather then Mac?

I am trying to compile https://github.com/relgames/keepassx on Qt5

Comment: How do you run qmake? Maybe you need to specify a different mkspec (platform).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update it to qt5 but failed. Almost everything is done except x11EventFilter.
My failed attempt is available here https://github.com/relgames/keepassx/tree/qt5

If you just need to build&run, use qmake-qt4 && make (clean the dir first).